# What are the advantages of using Layers in Docker

Tags: docker, dockerfile

what are the advantages of using Layer in Docker particularly at the aspect of "running", not "building"?

I read Docker Docs, googled a lot, saw the article ( [What are the advantages of having layers in a docker image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45676176/what-are-the-advantages-of-having-layers-in-a-docker-image) )

Then, I figured out what the advantages of using Layers are when I build images.

But I don't know what the advantages are, at the aspect of running containers based on the images.

For example(when I build an Image),
There is the following line in my Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.7-slim
```

If I have the python:3.7-slim image, I don't have to download another python image, so I can build it more efficiently and faster.

But it is the advantages about "building process". I want to know the advantages about "running".
What are the advantages of using Layers in Docker at the aspect of "running"?

Comment: The advantage is that if you have multiple docker images they can share layers and save disk space and share disk cache. It is also easier to manage. But that is closer to "running"

Comment: Thank you for your comment. But I wonder how images can share layers.
If an image includes FROM python:3.7-slim and another image also includes the line, Do they share the python image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no advantage at run time, even more it can be seen as a disadvantage.

Layers is a feature provided by [*union* file systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UnionFS). As you figured out, it is quite convenient to speed up docker image builds. But such a file system is **slower** than regular file system when it comes to I/O speed.

To overcome this drawback, there are [docker volumes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/) which are mount points within a container making use of a normal file system. *Docker volumes* also helps with persisting data because the data they hold is not on the container's union file system and thus, can survive container deletion (container union file system deletion).